# Аналог FileReference для Java?

Tags: applet, java, безопасность

Доброго времени суток!

Если кто сталкивался, подскажите. В ActionScript предусмотрен класс FileReference, который позволяет работать из флеша с локальными файлами системы (пользователю выдается диалог, и если он его подтверждает, то скрипт может получить доступ к выбранному файлу на чтение или запись (смотря, что запрашивали)).

Есть ли аналоги для Java-applet?

Есть решение на основе подписывания апплета, но как бы не слишком хотелось бы им пользователся (и потом доказывать пользователям, что апплет читает и пишет только то, что разрешили). Естественно можно ещё все замутить через веб-формы - но это очень не изящьно.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых не JAVA, а Java!

Во вторых: посмотрите в сторону [JNLP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/) (он же в простонародье [Java Web Start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start)), пример с доступом через песочницу к файловой системе описан [здесь](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs)

Comment: Супер! Спасибо. Результат выглядит конечно чуть менее красиво, чем хотелось, но это безспорно оно.